# declaring variable causes crash

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I've been writing this Visual Studio solution over a few years. Everything has been fine. I added a project to it to experiment, and decided to remove that project from the solution. Now my main project will not start. I get a 
"Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in 360Automation.exe" error in a place that should not be giving me that error. I've done a bit of research and discovered that it might have something to do with the compiler or debug session. I've deleted (I think it was) bin folders from my project's debug folders, restarted VS and my PC. The problem persists.

```
Partial Public Class main
Dim myPen As New System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Red, 2)
Dim pingresultpeak As Integer
Dim uptime As New TimeSpan(0, 0, 0)
Public bumptime = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 0)
Public breaktime = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 0)
Public hourremaining = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 0)            <- crash
Public GetScheduleMark As Boolean
```

If I remove that line, it decides to crash on a different yet similar line such as the one before it. If I remove the whole block of code, it crashes somewhere else I'm declaring a variable. My whole project is bricked because of this issue. I'd love to find a definitive answer to what's causing this and how to prevent it from happening again.

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you move the assignments into a named constructor instead of using initializers?

Comment: Has it always been called `main`?

Comment: What kind of application? WPF, WinForms, Console?

Comment: @Dai, Same thing.  It's a WinForms app that has not otherwise changed. All the code is the same as it was last week, except now it doesn't work.

Comment: is it possible your debug symbols don't match the execution code and the error is actually on a different error.  Delete the obj AND bin folders with VS closed and try to recompile

Comment: Try doing a Clean Solution

Comment: I forgot to mention I tried Clean Solution before coming here.

Comment: I'm seeing that if I were to change the line to  
    Public hourremaining As TimeSpan
Then it won't crash on that line but moves on (up) to the previous line, unless I change that. Then it moves on to crash on a different line that does declare a value upon initialization. I don't think I understood @Dai's question earlier.